# Symfony2 dynamic form builder

Tags: symfony

I want to create a bundle in an application where the user has the ability to create forms.

These forms will be questionnaires with different answers. Do you know if there is already a similar bundle exists?

If it does not exist. How should I proceed? I always create the forms only on files like "Form\Type\UserType".

In this case, would have to be generated dynamically from the database, right? Only I miss the approach, can anyone give a hint on how I can realize this?

**Update**:

Maybe i think to complicated. I'm not sure if an form service solve my problem. Know i created a database structure to describe my initial situation.

The user can create on a backend following records.

- A scale, a scale can contain many answers (yes, no, maybe, good, better ...)
- A question category
- A question, can be assigned to many categories and many questionnairies
- A questionnaire, can contain many questions and here can the user assign a scale to a question.

*Table Scale*

`+----+--------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+
| id |  name  | alignment  | isActive | isDeleted | createDate |
+----+--------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | Yes-No | horizontal |        1 |         1 | 2014-09-25 |
+----+--------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+`

*Table Items*

`+----+------+-------+------------+
| id | name | value | createDate |
+----+------+-------+------------+
|  1 | Yes  |     1 | 2014-09-25 |
|  2 | No   |     0 | 2014-09-25 |
+----+------+-------+------------+`

*ManyToMany 'scale_items'*

`+----------+----------+
| scale_id | items_id |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |
|        1 |        2 |
+----------+----------+`

*Table category for question categories*

`+----+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| id |  name   | isActive | isDeleted | createDate |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | General |        1 |         0 | 2014-09-25 |
+----+---------+----------+-----------+------------+`

*Table question*

`+----+-----------------------------------------+------------+
| id |                question                 | createDate |
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------+
|  1 | Are you satisfied with the cleanliness? | 2014-09-25 |
+----+-----------------------------------------+------------+`

*ManyToMany 'question_category'*

`+-------------+-------------+
| question_id | category_id |
+-------------+-------------+
|           1 |           1 |
+-------------+-------------+`

*Table questionnaire*

`+----+-------------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
| id |       name        | version | isActive | isDeleted | createDate |
+----+-------------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | General Questions | 2.2     |        1 |         0 | 2014-09-25 |
+----+-------------------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+`

Now the database contain scales and items, questions and categories and a table for the questionnaire. Now i created a big relation to assign questions to questionnairies with a specified scale. A question can be assigned to different scales on different questionaries.

*Table questionnaire_question_scale*

`+----+-------------+------------------+----------+------+--------+
| id | question_id | questionnaire_id | scale_id | page |  hash  |
+----+-------------+------------------+----------+------+--------+
|  1 |           1 |                1 |        1 |    1 | X321Z1 |
+----+-------------+------------------+----------+------+--------+`

In the final step i create a relation table to assign a questionnaire to a couple of users.

*Table questionnaire_user*

`+---------+------------------+
| user_id | questionnaire_id |
+---------+------------------+
|      21 |                1 |
+---------+------------------+`

Now if the user log in i will render the above informations as form and here starts my problem :)

I think my solution was inefficient, because if many users log in to fill out a questionnaire i must generate every time the questionnaire (the complex structure) as form.

This is a end point for me, unfortunately I do not know further.

I would be very grateful for ideas, tips and solution approaches

Comment: Give a look at poll or survey bundles : https://packagist.org/search/?tags=survey https://packagist.org/packages/bait/poll-bundle or https://github.com/Bodaclick/EnquiryBundle

Comment: You can build forms dynamically by following this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html . But you will almost certainly be better off with an existing bundle.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build it yourself: I suggest creating a form type, declaring it as a service and injecting the form repository (explained further down) in it.For storing it in the data base: you can create two entities (actually creating a seperate entity for each field seems better but for the sake of simplicity I use two entities) : one for forms : `YourBundle:Form` and one for your form-fields `YourBundle:FormField`.the `Form` entity can only contain an `id` and a `name` and a one-to-many association to `FormField`. the data you store in the `FormField` will be: a many-to-one association to `Form` - the field name - the field type - the field's options.you can store the options as Json or other formats and later decode it.